# AngularJS & IntelliJ / WebStorm - Code completion

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, autocomplete, webstorm

For some reason I can not do any auto completion in IntelliJ/WebStorm. For some reason I see bunch of other items but none of my functions. Only when I enter like 3-4 letters of function than IntelliJ drops me a suggestion for the function which I would like to use.

I did see various of tips but none are worked:

- Adding Angular into the "Settings | JavaScript Lib"
- Cleaning Cache and Restart IDE
- Created a brand new Project with AngularJS.

[image: Example Code - Not working]

I would like expect something like this :

[image: Expectation Code]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work currently; please follow [WEB-21738](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21738) for updates

Comment: Funny is, that my another project which is already in development since years, this works fine. Only new projects are not working.